# How to reset password on Jenkins War Ubuntu 20.04 (Azure VM)

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, war, azure-vm

I am tasked to setup Jenkins correctly. However it is found that the Ubuntu server I am currently on already has Jenkins war running (see below on the running processes). However no one has any idea what is the credentials of the login and I plan to wipe this account and start over creating a new admin account.

Is there any way to do that?

EDIT: I decided to completely removed Jenkins and reinstall it. Problem solved for my case.

Comment: If you do not know the history of this system, leave it alone, or maybe just stop the VM. Build a new system and configure Jenkins. Is your question how to change the user account or the Jenkins account?

Comment: @JohnHanley I just want to bypass the admin login. And recreating the VM is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep yet to comment, but I agree with John Hanley that you should probably configure a new Jenkins server instead.  However, if you insist on resetting the admin credentials of the existing one...

I don't remember the full details and I don't have a Jenkins server handy, but IIRC if you disable security in the Jenkins config and the restart Jenkins, you should be able to login without the need to enter any credentials.  You should then be able to go in and delete the Admin account and recreate it...(??) Sorry -- details are fuzzy from here on out.